# Implement an authorization layer for your restify API endpoints

Tags: node.js, restify

I am pretty new to restify and nodejs in general. I am attempting to build a rest api using restify and nodejs, and I need to implement a token-based authentication layer, or middleware if you will. On login, I generate a jwt token, which I save to a database, and I would like to validate the users token before allowing them to access particular endpoints. I have found a lot of information on how to do this using the Express framework, similar to this example below

```
function middlewareHandler(req, res, next) {
    console.log("execute middle ware");
    next();
}

app.get('/', middlewareHandler, function (req, res) {
    console.log("end middleware function");
    res.send("page render finished");
});
```

but so far I haven't been able to find anything similar for Restify. 
Can anyone please provide me some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: What kind of auth?  Name/Password?  Token?  Passport?  Oauth?

Comment: [What is the best way to implement a token-based authentication for restify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411946/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-token-based-authentication-for-restify-js) or [Using Passport auth with restify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-restify) or [Build an API Service with OAuth2 Authentication, using Restify and Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-api-restify-stormpath).  Found these with 2 minutes of Google searching.  I think you need to do a little more homework on your own and then post a more specific question.

Comment: I found those samples as well, but they didn't quite help explain what i'm trying to achieve. I edited the question in an attempt to make it more descriptive

Comment: The 3 links I provided showed you specific examples of doing auth with restify.  The example you added to your question is an Express example.  It appears that you simply haven't done your own research yet and have not experimented with some of the restify examples and then have not made your question about the specific problems you ran into in your experiment.  What you have now is off-topic for stack overflow as too broad.